# Why isn't jQuery native to browsers, i.e. pre-downloaded?

Tags: jquery

jQuery very popular, so why don't browsers wire in the last few versions of jQuery, going a little further than the current CDN?

No more downloading, no more manual updating, pre-compilation of the library (faster loading time), less worry for developers, better browsing experience for users, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume **version control** is the fear...

different sites use different versions of jQuery...

**AND**

the last thing I want is the elephants in the room (google, microsoft, and mozilla) fighting over implementation details of a **very successful and independant** open source project...

Comment: Include the last few versions?

Comment: but which one is loaded and used???

Comment: Well could add a line like `load(jQuery.1.6.2);` or something. It's a step further than the CDN.

Comment: the last thing I want is the elephants in the room fighting over implementation details of a **very successful** open source project...

Comment: No, it's not a step further than the CDN.  CDN files will remain cached forever.

Answer (score 3):

That will defeat the point of jQuery.

Any native implementation is guaranteed to have some subtle difference from the real thing; eventually, we would need a cross-browser *jQuery* wrapper, and the cycle would repeat.

It would also make updates much more complicated.

re: **EDIT**:
That's already done.
Google serves jQuery from [their public CDN](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js) with very heavy caching headers.

In practice, if you include jQuery from Google's CDN, it will usually be in the browser's cache.

Comment: "Any native implementation is guaranteed to have some subtle difference from the real thing" ... especially if we're talking about internet explorer

Comment: I was thinking of going further than the CDN... I wonder if there are statistics regarding the use of Google's CDN.

Comment: @Random: CDN files get cached in the browser.  You really can't do any better than the CDN.

Comment: I regularly empty my cache, for example. And there are many CDNs out there. And I know companies (such as the one I work for) that doesn't use the Google CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Because jQuery is a framework; not a language.

So by supporting Javascript it supports jQuery.

I see your point, and perhaps it will become ubiquitous enough that it just comes wired in, but I doubt it.

Comment: It's not a matter of support, more a matter of _performance_ and _convenience_.